# JavaScript Object property always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, azure-mobile-services

Tell me what I am missing here. I have the follow javascript object.

```
[ { id: '16B0C2FC-A008-4E8A-849B-DB1251C8CABD',
    handle: '123',
    userId: 'ABC123'} ]
```

When I do the following

```
success: function (registration) {
                console.log(registration);
                console.log(registration.handle);
```

Console log writes out the object as defined above. However when I do registration.handle I get an error saying "undefined." If registration is the above object why does registration.handle not work?

what am I missing?

Comment: In addition to the answers, you might also have to parse the response, with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too specific to a single code base.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an array containing an object. The properties you are trying to access are members of the object, not the array.

You must first get a reference to the object before you access its properties.

```
registration[0].handle
```

Comment: Thanks!! Should have seen that. To late and been looking at it for to long.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var registration=[ { id: '16B0C2FC-A008-4E8A-849B-DB1251C8CABD', handle: '123', userId: 'ABC123'} ]

alert(registration[0].handle)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WwvCP/)

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the member of an object.

Do it like this way

```
success: function(registration) {
        $.each(registration, function(index, data) {
            var handle = data.handle;
            console.log('id is getting now ' + handle);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you first need to access array element then you can find object

```
console.log(registration[0].handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are having array so to access it try

```
  registration[0].handle
```

EXAMPLE

**CASE 1**

```
registration =  [ { id: '16B0C2FC-A008-4E8A-849B-DB1251C8CABD', handle: '123', userId: 'ABC123'} ];
console.log(registration[0].handle);
```

**CASE 2**

```
registration = { id: '16B0C2FC-A008-4E8A-849B-DB1251C8CABD', handle: '123', userId: 'ABC123'};
console.log(registration.handle);
```