# Access content of JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, requestjs

I am attempting to access the content of a JSON object returned from an API call in order to set variables.

```
var request = require('request');
var apiOptions = { server : "http://localhost:3000" };


var renderAdminLanding = function(req, res, body){
  var str = JSON.stringify(body.content, null, 2);
  res.render('admin_landing', {
    title: str});
}
module.exports.landing = function(req, res){
  var reqOptions, path;
  path = '/api/student';
  reqOptions = {
    url : apiOptions.server + path,
    method : "GET",
    json : true
  }
  request(reqOptions, function(err, response, body){
    renderAdminLanding(req, res, body);
  });
};
```

In this case body.content returns:

```
[ { "_id": "58ca92faa0c1e14922000008", 
    "name": "Smarty", 
    "password": "McSmartface", 
    "__v": 0, 
    "Courses": [] } ]
```

So body.content.name, for example returns nothing.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: `body.content` is an array. To access the first element in that array, you have to write `body.content[0]`, and to get the name of the first element `body.content[0].name`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Object property always returns undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716618/javascript-object-property-always-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @t.niese said, `body.content` is an array. You can say that it's an array because your object is encased in square brackets: `[{"myObject": 3}]`.

Since `body.content` is an array, you have to get the position that your object is on the array. While `body.content.name` does not exist and will return undefined or throw an error, `body.content[0].name` will return `Smarty`, which is what you expected.