# How to specify to return JSONArray from Ajax call jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've been reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716618/javascript-object-property-always-returns-undefined), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined) until I reached [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289844/difference-between-jsonobject-and-jsonarray).

Basically what I'm trying to do is just iterate the data returned from an Ajax call which is `json_encode`d in the php side.

This is the structure of the object that returned when I use `console.log(data)`:

```
Object {0: "218", 1: "SCT_22156", 2: "10456", 3: "S5_MAN_Artwork-Processing", 4: "Duma Guete", ID: "218", ARTICLE_ID: "SCT_22156", METADATA_ID: "10456", FROM_STAGE: "S5_MAN_Artwork-Processing", SEND_FROM: "Duma Guete"}
```

What I use to iterate is this (I would like to get each value from each key, so example I would like to get the `metadata_id`):

```
$.each(data, function( k, v ) {
    console.log(v.METADATA_ID);
});
```

But this returns `undefined`.

**Note:** During ajax call data returned maybe one or more object.

What I noticed, it doesn't return `undefined` when the data returned is more than one object, thus making it JSONArray. So if the data returned is like this:

```
Object [{"data":"value"..},{"data":"value"..}]
```

`$.each` works fine.

Is there anyway that I can specifically tell the server side (`php`) should return JSONArray even it contains one object only?

I tried using `for in loop` too, but in reverse it doesn't work with JSONArray. I tried adding `timeouts` too, but no luck. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: ,
    data:,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data){
            $.each(data, function( k, v ) {
                console.log(v.SEND_FROM);
            }); 
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
        }
});
```

I tried using this trick:

```
$.each([data], function( k, v ) {
    console.log(v.METADATA_ID);
});
```

Adding brackets,but it will cause `undefined` for JSONArray(multiple object) result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to distinguish whether `data` is an array or a single object? If so, I'd suggest checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array) post.

Since you're using jQuery you can use `isArray`:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: ,
    data:,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data){
            if ($.isArray(data))
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    console.log(data[i]['SEND_FROM']);
            }

            else
                console.log(data['SEND_FROM']);
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
        }
});
```

Comment: it's not really the direct answer that I needed but your `$.isArray` help me to find another way around. Thank you.